# Windows 7 SWT Table selected row highlight color

Tags: java, windows-7, swt

Is there a way to set the background color of a highlighted row of a SWT Table (FULL_SELECTION style) in Windows 7's Aero theme? It appears that it's a derived, lighter color from the background color of the Table. But other than that, I don't seem to have much control over what color to use.

This is a problem to us because some of our table items' texts (foreground) are grayish whites, so they are very harder to read if the row is selected on a light-colored background. I've already set the background color of the table to Black, but the text is still pretty hard to see.

Are there any suggestions on how to control the color?

Thank you!
RAY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to SWT Win32 source file, exactly [line 1611](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/win32/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.java#n1611)

```
if ((style & SWT.FULL_SELECTION) != 0) bits1 |= OS.LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT;
```

the graphics style of `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` is get directly from OS (for `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` see [Extended List-View Styles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So it's not possible to change the style..